# Lambda function calling MediaConvert SDK to describeEndpoints timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-media-convert

I am just attempting to call describeEndpoints of mediaconvert SDK but seems like it times out, why could that be. I already gave my Lambda function admin access. I set timeout to 30s which should be more than sufficient but it still fails

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const util = require('util');

async function test() {
    let mediaconvert = new AWS.MediaConvert();
    const describeEndpoints = util
        .promisify(mediaconvert.describeEndpoints)
        .bind(mediaconvert);
    return await describeEndpoints()
}
```

Comment: All AWS JavaScript SDK methods have a promise equivalent, for example: let rc = await mediaconvert.describeEndpoints().promise().

Comment: Have you launched lambda in vpc ? if so, check if it has nat gateway , lambda doesn't work with subnet with route igw.

Comment: @JamesDean I think you are right, let me check

Comment: @jarmod good point

Comment: @JamesDean just added NAT to my route table and allowed all traffic for security group in and out. Same for NACL. It seems like it can describeEndpoints but cannot getJob... what could possibily be wrong? Its not a permissions error it seems cos it has the IAM permission and its a timeout and not 403

Comment: @JamesDean you can actually make it an answer, its timing out not because of mediaconvert calls but because my DB security group was incorrect. So the main thing I needed was the NAT gateway and HTTPS out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you launched lambda in vpc ? if so, check if it has nat gateway , lambda doesn't work with subnet with route igw.

Comment: What is a nat gateway? How do you check it? What are you meant to check for?

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of describing then:

```
const mediaConvert = new AWS.MediaConvert(
{ endpoint: 'MEDIACONVERT REGIONAL API ENDPOINT', });
```